# how to import and display csv file in django project

Tags: django, templates, django-views, django-templates

I have two different project and one of them is a django project . 
I want to import the csv file and display it in html template . but since I'm a beginner I read a lot of articles and none of them helped me ?

Answer (score 1):

Reading csv in Python is pretty easy with the module called csv

```
context={"csv_rows" : []} 
with open('file_name.csv') as csvfile:
       reader = csv.reader(csvfile)
       for row in reader:
           context["csv_rows"].append(" ".join(row))
```

Then pass context to your template and output it like

```
{% for row in csv_rows %}
    {{ row }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: thank you but I tried it and nothing is displayed . my csv contains two columns and 10 rows .  do I have to include something like a model or database . althought I have to only to display the csv in an html table .

Comment: How do you pass  the context to your template? Please state the render() call.
To show it in a table you can just but the {{ row }} part in a <tr> and <td> tag